# Nested JSON string to dictionary with object to be used as key

Tags: javascript, json

I am loading a nested JSON query and I am trying to create a dictionary that will have a specific object as a key. Sp, in my case, the key will be the country and then each dictionary value will have the date and the number. I have made a progress but I am stuck at the final function. My snippet prints all the steps in the HTML part.

So, I am actually trying to convert this:

```
2018-05-01,Italy,25,2018-04-01,Italy,37,2018-05-01,France,30,2018-04-01,France,90
```

to this:

```
{"Italy":[{"Date":"2018-04-01","num":37},{"Date":"2018-05-01","num":25}],"France":[{"Date":"2018-04-01","num":90},{"Date":"2018-05-01","num":30}]}
```

which will then be converted to:

```
[
  {
    "Value": "Italy",
    "num": 37,
    "num2": 25
  },
  {
    "Value": "France",
    "num": 90,
    "num2": 30
  }
]
```

where `num` will have the number of the first date and `num2` will have the number of the second date.

Also, feel free to provide a completely different solution if you believe that my steps are too many.

```js
var json_data = {"headers":["Month","Country","Number"],"rows":[["2018-05-01","Italy",25],["2018-04-01","Italy",37],["2018-05-01","France",30],["2018-04-01","France",90]
]};

var dataRows = json_data.rows;
document.getElementById("yellow").innerHTML = dataRows;

//Returns unique values of a specific object of a JSON string
uniqueValues = (data,objectNum) => {

var uniqueValues = [];
data.forEach(function(item) {
    var value = item[objectNum];
    if (uniqueValues.indexOf(value) !== -1)
    return false;

    uniqueValues.push(value);
});

return uniqueValues;
}

var uniqueCountries = uniqueValues(dataRows,1);
document.getElementById("green").innerHTML = uniqueCountries;
var uniqueDates = uniqueValues(dataRows,0);
document.getElementById("blue").innerHTML = uniqueDates;

//Create dictionary function (transformed JSON)
createDict = (data,objectNum) => {
  var dict =[];
  var num = 0;
  var num2 = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) 
  {
    var object = {"Date": dataRows[i][0].slice(0,10), "Value": dataRows[i][1], "num": dataRows[i][2]};
    dict.push(object);      
  }
  return dict;
  
}

var dictData = createDict(dataRows,2);
document.getElementById("orange").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dictData);


//Function that will return the final output
function test (){
  var sumMetric = {}; 
  dictData.forEach(function(d) {
     
    uniqueCountries.forEach(function(country) {
      console.log(d.Date);
       //d.num = +d.num;
        sumMetric[country] = []; 
        uniqueDates.forEach(function(element) {
          sumMetric[country].push({Date: d.Date, num: d.num});
        });
     });
     
  });
  
  document.getElementById("red").innerHTML =JSON.stringify(sumMetric);
  return sumMetric;

}
    
test();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<h4>Original JSON</h4>
<div style="background:yellow;" id="yellow"></div>
<h4>Unique Countries</h4>
<div style="background:green; color:white" id="green"></div>
<h4>Unique Dates</h4>
<div style="background:blue; color:white" id="blue"></div>
<h4>Dictionary Creation</h4>
<div style="background:orange;" id="orange"></div>
<h4>Wrong Output</h4>
<div style="background:red;" id="red"></div>
<h4>Expected Output</h4>
<div style="background:purple; color:white" id="purple">{"Italy":[{"Date":"2018-04-01","num":37},{"Date":"2018-05-01","num":25}],"France":[{"Date":"2018-04-01","num":90},{"Date":"2018-05-01","num":30}]}</div>

<h4>Final Output that I need</h4>
<div style="background:grey; color:black" id="purple">[
  {
    "Value": "Italy",
    "num": 37,
    "num2": 25
  },
  {
    "Value": "France",
    "num": 90,
    "num2": 30
  }
]<div>
```

Comment: Please explain more explicitly what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the array of arrays in your snippet is the correct input dataset to start with (rather than the string posted at the beginning of your question)...

If the original array is guaranteed to only have 2 sub-arrays for each country, then you can use `reduce` to group it into an object by country key and then compare the array pairs in the grouped object to produce the desired results. For example:

```js
const data = [["2018-05-01", "Italy", 25], ["2018-04-01", "Italy", 37], ["2018-05-01", "France", 30], ["2018-04-01", "France", 90]];
const groups = data.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  if (acc.hasOwnProperty(arr[1])) {
    acc[arr[1]].push(arr);
  } else {
    acc[arr[1]] = [arr];
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

let results = [];
for (const g in groups) {
  const obj = { value: g };
  const a = groups[g][0];
  const b = groups[g][1];
  if (a[0] <= b[0]) {
    obj.num = a[2];
    obj.num2 = b[2];
  } else {
    obj.num = b[2];
    obj.num2 = a[2];
  }
  
  results.push(obj);
}

console.log(results);
```

If the original array is not guaranteed to have only 2 sub-arrays for each country, then you would have to modify the `for...in` loop above to loop through and compare multiple country arrays (rather than just comparing a single pair) and update the result objects as needed.